# Sublime text showing previous version icon

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, .desktop, sublime-text

When I search for sublime in the "search your computer" box, it shows the icon like this:

[image: New Icon]

Now when I open the application, the previous sublime text icon is shown as in image here:

[image: Old icon]

**How do I replace the old icon with the new one?**

Comment: Look in `~/.local/share/applications` for duplicate `.desktop` files. If you installed it globally, you don't need any in `~/.local/share/applications`, unless you deliberately made modifications. Local .dektop files overrule global ones, they will not update if you update the application, hence the obsolete icon.

Comment: Just curious, but did you even look? ^

Comment: @JacobVlijm  yes i went in .desktop file and just changed the path where the new logo is present

Comment: If that changes it, that means that the .desktop file you edited the icon path of can actually be deleted. That's the outdated one.

Answer (score 0):

UnInstall it

```
sudo apt-get remove sublime-text && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And install it back

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

will fix this.

Comment: i want sublime 3 so i downloaded tar and what should i do to install it

Comment: its `ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3` already

Comment: check this http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html

Comment: i copy pasted the commands... installed the basic version for me

Comment: what ? i used this to update mine 3days ago. Check this http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html